# 6 Divs over a Img - Angular

Tags: html, angular

i have an car image and i want to have 6 divs over the image which i can select with mouse. For example if i click a div with the mouse this div will change the color.
I tried already with z-index but either it doesn't work with z-index or i'm doing it wrong somehow

what i have [current situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWTBT.png)

```
<img class="col-lg-12" [src]="data.car" />
```

but i need this one:
[what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dj3qW.png)

in this project i want to select which part of the car have damage by selecting the div..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place tags (divs) on image with `absolute` position.
Here is my snippet :

CSS

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

img{
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
.tag {
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.row-1{
  top: 0px;
}

.row-2{
  top: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tag row-1" style="left:0%;"></div>
  <div class="tag row-1" style="left:33%;"></div>
  <div class="tag row-1" style="left:66%;"></div>

  <div class="tag row-2" style="left:0%;"></div>
  <div class="tag row-2" style="left:33%;"></div>
  <div class="tag row-2" style="left:66%;"></div>

  <img src="https://www.autotrader.co.uk/home-pages/images/static/covid-panel/red-car-v2.png">
</div>
```

You can solve this problem
more sophisticated but I don't have time now on that. Also if you want to get div (example for `ViewChild`), you can set id or something identifiable tag. If you have any issue let me know.
[More about position](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

**Result**

[image]